# Java - printing to multiple outputs with a socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to create a multithreaded chatroom that multiple people can attach to. The goal is that when one person sends a message, the message gets printed on everyone else's screen. Here's the server code:

```
package edu.fcps.ab;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestServer implements Runnable{
    private int port;
    public static ServerSocket serverSock;
    public static Vector<PrintWriter> outputs = new Vector<PrintWriter>();
    public PrintWriter output;
    public BufferedReader input;
    public TestServer(int p) {
        port = p;
    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter port number");
        int port = scan.nextInt();
        TestServer ts = new TestServer(port);
        Thread t = new Thread(ts);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(serverSock == null)
                 serverSock = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket sock = serverSock.accept();
            TestServer ts = new TestServer(port);
            Thread t = new Thread(ts);
            t.start();
            output = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), false);
            outputs.add(output);
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            while(t.isAlive()) {
                String message = input.readLine();
                if(message != null) {
                    System.out.println(message);
                    for(PrintWriter w : outputs) {
                        w.println(message);
                        w.flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public PrintWriter getOutput() {
        return output;
    }
}
```

Here's the client code:

```
package edu.fcps.ab;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TestClient implements Runnable{
    private String username;
    public PrintWriter out;
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        TestClient tc = new TestClient();
        Thread t = new Thread(tc);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter port");
        int port = s.nextInt();
        String ip = "127.0.0.1";
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket(ip, port);
            System.out.println("Successfully connected");
            System.out.println("Enter username");
            username = s.next();
            System.out.println("Welcome " + username);
            out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println(username + " connected");
            InputStream stream = sock.getInputStream();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(stream);
            BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String sent;
            while(true) {
                if(stream.available() > 0) {
                    if(input.hasNextLine()) {
                        String message = input.nextLine();
                        String[] split = message.split(" ");
                        if(!(split[0].contains(username)))
                            System.out.println(message);
                    } 
                }
                sent = stdin.readLine();
                if(sent != null) {
                    out.println(username + ": " + sent);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            out.println(username + " disconnected");
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, multiple people can attach to it, and it prints out all the messages on the server side, but the messages aren't getting printed on all the clients. Why is this happening?

Comment: is each message only showing up once on a random client?

Comment: @0TTT0 no, the messages aren't showing up on any client

Comment: Why ar you creating `TestServer` twice? And why the `isAlive()` test? This code doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user207421 `TestServer` is created multiple times so that each client will be on its own thread, allowing for simultaneous reading and writing. The `isAlive()` test is pretty much useless, and I forgot to take it out

Comment: This is not the normal technique. See the Custom Networkng section of the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

> … but the messages aren't getting printed on all the clients. Why is this happening?

This happens because all the clients call `stdin.readLine()` and block there until an input line is available; thereafter they continue the `while(true)` loop and print up to one message before they again block in `stdin.readLine()`.